# Non-Tactical Puzzles

Tags: tactics, training, puzzles, recommendations, solving

Its surprisingly hard to find chess puzzles where the solution is not necessarily tactic resulting in checkmate or a heavy win of material.  The problem with these tactical puzzles is that they do not simulate a real game where the best move may be something less exciting.  Does anyone know of any good books or online resources for puzzles with solutions representing a wider variety of types of moves?

Comment: Related:  [Exercises with positions where the best move isn't always a tactical one](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/40221/26335)

Comment: It's not that hard. There are plenty of books on non-tactical puzzles! It's just like with openings. It's not like there are too few good books on openings. It's just they are not targeting beginners most of the time. Positional puzzles, specific openings, pawn structures, middlegame themes, etc. target very serious players. Try Euwe's _Master vs Chess Amateur_ and _Formation Attacks_ by Johnson. It's not what you want. But that is how things are!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a good book by Ray Cheng that has 600 puzzles with a good variety of solutions - not just tactical.

There are also some youtube videos with similar types of puzzles -- for example:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94hiFJrtQWA